# Configuring local git with CircleCI

Tags: automation, devops, circleci

how can I connect circleCI with my Local Git server?
we have installed Git locally on ubuntu machine for push our code, we don't use github or bitbucket etc. we only use Local Git server.

when I Try to sign in circleci it show sign in with Github or bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, so far, it won't be possible from CircleCI to access a private git server.

Indeed the CircleCI hosting options features for Cloud hosting: only VCS Provider (GitHub and Bitbucket).
And even with the self-hosted solution the VCS Provider supported are: GitHub
and GitHub Enterprise.

Here is the link to this information: https://circleci.com/product/#hosting-options

You might have more success dropping a note to the CircleCI support team if a solution exists they might not be publicly available.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. so that’s mean we have to must transfer our code from local git server to Github, Github Enterprise or Bitbucket for integration with CircleCI. Is there any plugins or other way to use local Git with CircleCI?

Comment: I don't think so, but do not hesitate to ask the CircleCI support team